# "NSString stringWithFormat:" - Access same parameter multiple times?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, string-formatting

When I'm using string formatting, can I access one parameter multiple times without passing it again?

Example:

```
NSString *parameter1 = @"1";
NSString *parameter2 = @"2";

NSString *myString;
myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I want to print parameter1 here: %@, parameter2 here: %@ and now access parameter1 again: %@ _without_ passing it again.",parameter1, parameter2, parameter1];
```

Is there a way to access the first parameter again without writing ", parameter1" again?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Yes, using *positional arguments*:

```
// prints: foo bar foo bar
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2$@ %1$@ %2$@ %1$@", @"bar", @"foo"]);

// NSLog supports it too
NSLog(@"%2$@ %1$@ %2$@ %1$@", @"bar", @"foo");
```

Comment: Note that in the format string, you need to refer to all the arguments supplied in the argument list. eg. The following code will cause a bug at runtime, because the first positional argument is unused in the format string: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2$@", @"bar", @"foo"]` — see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946649/nsstring-stringwithformat-swizzled-to-allow-missing-format-numbered-args

Comment: @mrb Right. It's side effect of variable arguments (`...`) implementation in C (not a bug). If you don't tell formatting function what type an argument has (by refering to it at least once), there is no way to correctly locate ones after it.

Comment: i try it with predicateWithFormat but not working. how can use argument position for predicate ?

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *parameter1 = @"1";
NSString *parameter2 = @"2";

NSString *myString;
myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I want to print parameter1 here: %1$@, parameter2 here: %2$@ and now access parameter1 again: %1$@ _without_ passing it again.",parameter1, parameter2];
```

[String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)