# Multiple arguments in stringWithFormat: “n$” positional specifiers

Tags: ios, objective-c, stringwithformat

In our current implementation we want to change our string arguments (Push notification loc-args) and add new arguments. But we want user's of our old Versions to still use argument #3 and for new user's we want to user argument #4. So in our new implementation we have following code :

```
NSString *format = @"%2$@,  %1$@  ,%4$@";
NSArray *arg = @[@"Argument 1", @"Argument 2",@"Argument 3",@"Argument 4"];
NSString *ouptput = [NSString stringWithFormat:format, arg[0], arg[1], arg[2], arg[3]];
```

> OutPut: Argument 2,  Argument 1  ,Argument 3

We are expecting it to be

> Argument 2,  Argument 1  ,Argument 4

How can we achieve `Argument 4` in place. Any other alternative of `stringWithFormat:`

Note: Apple lock screen push notification is correct (`Argument 2,  Argument 1  ,Argument 4`) but `stringWithFormat:` not handles it that way

Comment: "old versions"?  of what?  If it's an app, then how would old versions even see the changes?

Comment: Actually arguments are sent via push notifications, so if we change arguments, 'Old Version' apps will get updated argument list. Only format is in the app.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944704/advanced-localization-with-omission-of-arguments-in-xcode: *"When numbered argument specifications are used, specifying the Nth argument **requires** that all the leading arguments, from the first to the (N-1)th, are specified in the format string."* – If you omit the 3rd argument in the format string then the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @MartinR you are right. But apple handles it. When presenting push notification, it will be displayed as `Argument 2,  Argument 1  ,Argument 4` on lock screen for above format and arguments. And I want to achieve the same within the app as well

Comment: Here is another workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946649/nsstring-stringwithformat-swizzled-to-allow-missing-format-numbered-args.

Comment: An external suggestion: Pass the version number of the app to the web service database while registering for remote notifications and send the payload depending on the version (you will get 0 or `nil` for the old versions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a custom method to achieve expected output. This method can handle missing positional specifier. This method will only work for format containing positional specifier `%n$@`.

```
/**
 @param format String format with positional specifier
 @param arg Array of arguments to replace positional specifier in format
 @return Formatted output string
 */
+(NSString*)stringWithPositionalSpecifierFormat:(NSString*)format arguments:(NSArray*)arg
{
    static NSString *pattern = @"%\\d\\$@";

    NSError *error;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

    NSMutableString *mString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:format];
    NSArray *allMatches = [regex matchesInString:format options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [format length])];
    if (!error && allMatches>0)
    {
        for (NSTextCheckingResult *aMatch in allMatches)
        {
            NSRange matchRange = [aMatch range];
            NSString *argPlaceholder = [format substringWithRange:matchRange];
            NSMutableString *position = [argPlaceholder mutableCopy];
            [position replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"%" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [position length])];
            [position replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"$@" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [position length])];
            int index = position.intValue;
            //Replace with argument
            [mString replaceOccurrencesOfString:argPlaceholder withString:arg[index-1] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [mString length])];
        }
    }
    return mString;
}
```