# Unused positional argument skipped in String formatting (Swift)

Tags: swift

I want to format a string, in Swift, with two potential arguments (using [Format specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265)). The string to format may have a place for only the first argument, only the second argument, or both arguments. If I use the first or both arguments it works, but if I use only the second argument, it does not work. For instance:

```
let title = "M."
let name = "David"
let greetingFormat = "Hello %1$@ %2$@"
print(String(format: greetingFormat, title, name))
// OUTPUT> Hello M. David
// OK
```

If I use only the first argument in the String to format:

```
let greetingFormat = "Hello %1$@"
print(String(format: greetingFormat, title, name))
// OUTPUT> Hello M.
// OK
```

But when using only the second argument

```
let greetingFormat = "Hello %2$@"
print(String(format: greetingFormat, title, name))
// OUTPUT> Hello M.
// NOT THE EXPECTED RESULT!
```

In the last case I expected "Hello David". Is it a bug? How can I obtain the intended result for the last case where only the second argument is used?

Remarks:

- Please note that this problem occurs in the context of localization (i.e. the string to format comes from a Localizable.strings file), so I don’t have the possibility to remove unused argument directly.
- The question does not relate to person’s name formatting. This is just taken as a example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27870553/2303865

Comment: Indeed `String(format:)` does not support omitting positional parameters. – According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2946880/1187415, this is *not* a bug.

Comment: Thanks [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r). I created an answer based on your comment but feel free to create your answer and I will mark it as accepted to credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question but all credit to [@Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) that provides the relevant information in comments.

- It is *not* a bug, `String(format:)` does not support omitting positional parameters.
- It is a known behavior since ObjectiveC, see: [stackoverflow.com/a/2946880/1187415](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2946880/1187415)
- If you only have String arguments you can use multiple String substitutions with `String.replacingOccurrences(of:, with:)` instead of `String(format:)`.

More precision on the last solution. The following will work in the case that only one argument is used and also if both arguments are used in the `greetingFormat` String:

```
greetingFormat.replacingOccurrences(
    of: "%1$@", with: title)
    .replacingOccurrences(
    of: "%2$@", with: name)
```

Of course, with `String.replacingOccurrences(of:, with:)` you can choose other identifiers for the substitution than `%1$@` and `%2$@`.